# Kendo grid display time incorrectly

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

Is there a way to make the kendo grid not convert the time to Universal time.  For instance, my database returns a time of 07:00, but when displayed in the grid it displays as 02:00.  How do you make the column display the actual time you are returning?

This is the Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExerciseBreakdownViewModel>()
          .Name(string.Format("Grid"))
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.PersonnelName).Width(120);
              columns.Bound(p => p.NumberOfTeams).Width(120);
              columns.Bound(p => p.TeamMembers).Width(110);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Vehicles).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Brief).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("BriefTimePicker").Width(80);
              columns.Bound(p => p.KickOff).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("KickoffTimePicker").Width(80);
              columns.Bound(p => p.Debrief).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("DebriefTimePicker").Width(80);
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px;" })
          .Navigatable()
          .Scrollable()
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(20)
              .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.Id);
                  model.Field(p => p.PersonnelName).Editable(false);
                  model.Field(p => p.NumberOfTeams);
                  model.Field(p => p.TeamMembers);
                  model.Field(p => p.Vehicles);
                  model.Field(p => p.Brief);
                  model.Field(p => p.KickOff);
                  model.Field(p => p.Debrief);
              })
             .Read("Personnel_Read", "Schedule", Model)
          )
    )
```

The data coming back from the Database is of type Time.  When debugging it shows fine in the object getting sent to the grid, but when the grid reads it, it converts it.

Comment: how are you binding the time to the grid can you show the code

Comment: post the code please...

Comment: Please add an example of the data transmitted by your server to see how you are transmitting the time.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but do check out this: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides